# Using feature hashing/hashing tricks for machine learning in R

Tags: r, performance, machine-learning, hash, large-data

I just learned about [feature hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing) (also known as the hashing trick) and that some see it as an important feature for efficiently doing machine learning on large data sets.

However, I haven't seen anything like this being used for machine learning with R.

A Google search revealed that there is indeed a package `hash` on CRAN.

Could someone provide an example where this is used in R to speed up a machine learning task (or just to reduce RAM usage)?

Answer (score 4):

I submit a package named `FeatureHashing` recently. Please check the github page for demo: https://github.com/wush978/FeatureHashing and let me know if you have any issue of using it.